# Is an element in an array a reference to an object or a reference it self?

Tags: java, arrays, reference

If i have an array of AnObjects and i do this:

```
AnObject oldObject = arrayOfObjects[validIndex];
arrayOfObjects[validIndex] = new AnObject(oldObject.getVariableForContruction);
oldObject.terminate();
```

Does the new content of `arrayOfObjects[validIndex]` get terminated, or does the original `oldObject` get terminated?

In other words: Does oldObject contain a reference to an AnObject or does it contain a reference to a reference to an AnObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is a bit confusing.  Your array of objects must have a reference to `AnObject`.

```
AnObject oldObject = arrayOfObjects[validIndex];
```

You assign that reference to `oldObject` here.

```
arrayOfObjects[validIndex] = new AnObject(oldObject.getVariableForContruction);
```

Now you set the array reference at `validIndex` to point to a new instance of `AnObject`.  It no longer points to `oldObject`.

```
oldObject.terminate();
```

It's a reference to an object on the heap.

`oldObject` refers to an instance on the heap; the reference in the array points to the new instance that you created on the heap.

If `oldObject` is terminated (whatever that means), it's immaterial to the new instance you created.  The array still points to the new instance.

Comment: Sorry the naming terminate is in context with my project it could basicly be any method call, but so the method call is called on the new instance? Do i get that right?

Comment: No, if terminate is not static it's invoked on the instance - in your example's case, oldObject.  Not the new instance that you made the array reference to point to.

Answer (score 1):

It contains a reference to an object. In this case the oldObject would get terminated - not the new instance you have placed in the array.

Answer (score 1):

- Assume that arrayOfObjects starts at
  memory location 100.
- Assume that
  validIndex is 0.

Then arrayOfObjects[validIndex] means memory location 100.

- Assume that memory location 100 has a
  value of 200.

  AnObject oldObject = arrayOfObjects[validIndex];

oldObject is at memory location 200.

```
arrayOfObjects[validIndex] = new AnObject(oldObject.getVariableForContruction);
```

- Assume that the call to new allocated
  the object a memory location 300.

Then the memory location 100 has a value of 300.

```
oldObject.terminate();
```

oldObject never changed, so it is still pointing at memory location 200.

So, the item that used to be in the array is terminated after it is replaced with the new object.

Answer (score 0):

In Java there are no references to references. Ignoring primitive types, then all variables/array cells hold references to objects. Here's a snippet that illustrates this:

```
class Something {
  public int n;
}    

Something[] arr = new Something[2];
Something s = new Something();
s.n = 2;

arr[0] = s;
System.out.print(arr[0].n); // Output: "2"
arr[0].n += 1;
System.out.print(s.n); // Output: "3"
```